# Standalone or integrated differentials with correct spacing

Tags: spacing

Tons of answers on this site contain the correct way to adjust the spacing before `dx` at the end of integrals correctly, with or without upright font.

My need is to reuse the same definition and do not add spacing before a standalone differential, e.g. in `|dx|`, so both `\int|dx|` and `\int f(x)dx` typeset correctly with space inserted before the second `dx` and not before the first. Is there such a way?

Comment: Will post MWE later; sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong spacing comes from using `|` which is an ordinary symbol. You *must* tell TeX that it is used as opening/closing delimiter, either with `\mathopen`/`\mathclose` (unpractical), or using `amsmath`'s macros `\lvert`/`\rvert`, or (better) by defining e.g. `\abs` with `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{|}{|}

\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

$|\dd x|$ % bad

$\mathopen|\dd x\mathclose|$, $\lvert\dd x\rvert$ % good but clumsy

$\abs{\dd x}$ % better

$\int\abs{\dd x}$

$\int f(x) \dd x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I was barking up the wrong tree!

Comment: Let me think... are you saying that the culprit in `\newcommand*{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}`, which does not specify | as opening or end brackets? In my actual code I use this command for absolute values.

Comment: @FrenzyLi `\left`/`\right` should result in the correct spacing too, at least the inner one; the outer one will be wrong (the `mathtools` definition is better). If you get something else then there is something strange with your code (which you haven't shown, so I can only guess).

Comment: Hmm... I am working on something else right now, and will post a MWE later, but the addition of that single line of code defining the paired delimiter did solve the problem that I had.

Comment: Good answer (+1), but I think these are the three cases the OP is interested in, `$\abs{\dd x}$ % better

$\int\abs{\dd x}$

$\int f(x) \dd x$`, of which you cover the first only.  You might want to add them

Comment: I didn't mean the others shouldn't be covered, but I think the focus of the question concerned the `dx` in concert with both `||` and `\int`.  Your answer addressed well the first point *and your answer also addresses the 2nd point*, but you did not show that to the viewer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Oh sorry, yes I see, I misinterpreted the comment. But I still haven't a working instalation... sigh...

Comment: I have taken the liberty of providing the edit in your stead.